# x-y scatter-plot in r with labels on points

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, scatter-plot

I am trying to make an x-y scatter-plot. I don't mind if it's in plot or ggplot2. I don't know much about each, but I would like an example in both if you don't mind. I would like a label on the points.

Below is code and dput:

```
tickers <- rownames(x2)

library(zoo)
plot(x2, 
     main= "Vol vs Div",
     xlab= "Vol (in %)",
     ylab= "Div",
     col= "blue", pch = 19, cex = 1, lty = "solid", lwd = 2)

text(x=x2$Volatility101,y=x2$`12m yield`, labels=tickers,cex= 0.7, pos= 3)
```

---

x2:

```
structure(list(Volatility101 = c(25.25353177644, 42.1628734949414, 
28.527736824123), `12m yield` = c("3.08", "7.07", "4.72")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("EUN", 
"HRUB", "HUKX"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)

x2 %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "tickers") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Volatility101, y = `12m yield`)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = tickers)) +
  ggtitle("Vol vs Div") +
  xlab("Vol (in %)") +
  ylab("Div") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised that the `plot` function worked at all. The Y-values are character values. Fixing that in the text call results in text being placed in the expected locations

```
text(x=x2$Volatility101,y=as.numeric(x2$`12m yield`)+.1, labels=tickers,
            cex= 0.7, col='black')
```

A couple of notes about the question presentation: It's unclear (and misleading) why ggplot2 is a tag. The `plot` function is generic and in this case it uses base-graphics rather than either `ggplot2` specifically or `grid` graphics more generally. I also think that the `library(zoo)` call is probably unnecessary. There is a `plot.zoo` function, but it would not be called in this case.